# Manter apenas os 3 últimos arquivos de backup

Tags: php

Possuo um sistema que faz backup de informaçoes e as salva em uma pasta com este titulo: `db-backup-20150308-034000.sql` que é um titulo variante de acordo com a data e o tempo, vejamos que eu nao quero acumular arquivos entao eu quero manter apenas os 3 ultimos arquivos salvos, como proceder?

o título do arquivo é feito da seguinte formataçao:

`'db-backup-' . date("Ymd-His", time()) . '.sql'`

Answer (score 2):

O que você vai ter que fazer é basicamente o seguinte:

1. Buscar todos os arquivos do diretório e guardá-los num `array` usando [`readdir`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readdir.php).
2. Tratar o nome dos arquivos buscados e usar [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) para organizar as coisas.
3. Após isso, pegar os 3 primeiros valores da `array` (serão os arquivos mais recentes) e salvar numa `array` separada.
4. Buscar novamente o nome dos arquivos e verificar quais arquivos **não são** os 3 mais recentes e deletá-los, usar [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.glob.php) pra isso deixa o processo mais fácil.

Segue um exemplo rápido que fiz, você pode melhorar algumas coisas nele depois se preferir:

```
<?php
    $datetime   = array();
    $dir        = "test";
    $handle     = opendir($dir);

    if ($handle) {
        while ( $entry = readdir($handle) ) {
            // Não sei porquê aqui listou 2 arquivos inexistentes com nomes "." e "..", não sei mesmo.
            // Então montei essa condição, se você ver o erro no código me avise por favor.
            if ( strlen($entry) > 3 ) {
                // Adiciona à nossa array os valores no formato YmdHis
                array_push( $datetime,  str_replace( "-", "", substr($entry, 10, -4) ) );
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);

        // Aqui utilizamos o usort pra definir uma função de retorno que compara
        // os valores da array.
        usort($datetime, "doCompare");

        // Aqui já sabemos que os 3 arquivos mais recentes são os 3 primeiros da array
        // Criamos uma array auxiliar para remontarmos o nome completo dos arquivos
        $leave = array_slice($datetime, 0, 3);
        $leave_files = array();

        foreach ($leave as $key => $value) {
            array_push($leave_files, $dir . "/db-backup-" . date("Ymd-His", strtotime($value)) . ".txt");
        }

        // Usamos um glob para pegar os nomes dos arquivos do diretório
        $files = glob( $dir . "/*");

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            // Verifica se o arquivo NÃO ESTÁ na array de arquivos a serem mantidos
            // Se não estiver, tenta deletar o arquivo
            if ( !in_array($file, $leave_files) ) {
                if ( unlink($file) ) {
                    echo "- Arquivo deletado: " . $file . "<br />";
                } else {
                    echo "Falha no arquivo: " . $file . "<br />";
                }
            } else {
                echo "+ Arquivo mantido: " . $file . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }

    function doCompare($a, $b) {
        $t1 = strtotime($a);
        $t2 = strtotime($b);

        return ($t2 - $t1);
    }
```

Lista de todos arquivos do diretório antes da execução:

```
db-backup-20131111-224750.txt
db-backup-20140101-001712.txt
db-backup-20140123-153000.txt
db-backup-20140308-034000.txt
db-backup-20150101-001712.txt
db-backup-20150220-132907.txt
db-backup-20140123-153702.txt
db-backup-20140123-153212.txt
```

Saída da execução:

```
- Arquivo deletado: test/db-backup-20131111-224750.txt
- Arquivo deletado: test/db-backup-20140101-001712.txt
- Arquivo deletado: test/db-backup-20140123-153000.txt
- Arquivo deletado: test/db-backup-20140123-153212.txt
- Arquivo deletado: test/db-backup-20140123-153702.txt
+ Arquivo mantido: test/db-backup-20140308-034000.txt
+ Arquivo mantido: test/db-backup-20150101-001712.txt
+ Arquivo mantido: test/db-backup-20150220-132907.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

/*
Quantidade de arquivos para manter no diretório
*/
$files_qty = 3;

/*
Diretório base
*/
$dir_base = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

/*
Inicia iteração no diretório
*/
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator($dir_base);
foreach( $iterator as $fileinfo )
{
    if( $fileinfo -> isFile() )
    {
        /*
        Guarda os dados num array.
        As chaves do array são números inteiros criados automaticamente.
        O valor de cada array guarda a data de modificação/criação, em formato timestamp, do arquivo contatenado com o nome do mesmo.
        Exemplo: "1423409607 - arquivo_test.php" (sem aspas)
        */
        $arr[] = $fileinfo -> getMTime() . ' - ' . $fileinfo -> getFilename();
    }
}

/*
Verifica se o carray contém mais de 3 ítens.
*/
if( $arr > $files_qty )
{
    /*
    Reverte a ordenação do array baseado na string.
    É por isso que o timestamp é salvo concatenado ao nome do arquivo. Para facilitar nesse momento de ordenação e aplicação do array_slice()
    */
    rsort($arr);

    /*
    Aplicando a função array_slice(), a qual removerá os 3 primeiros da lista.
    A idéia é manter no array somente os nomes dos arquivos que devem ser excluídos.
    A função array_slice() é similar a função substr(), só que é usada para arrays.
    */
    $arr = array_slice( $arr, $files_qty );

    /*
    Itera pelo array resultante, excluindo todos os arquivos contidos na lista.
    */
    foreach( $arr as $v )
    {
        /*
        Apenas para debugar
        */
        echo PHP_EOL . $dir_base . substr( $v, 13 );

        /*
        Descomente a linha abaixo para proceder.
        Cuidado onde for executar pois os arquvios são excluídos permamentemente.
        A função substr() é necessária para pular a string que contém o timestamp e os caracteres separadores ( - ). O real nome do arquivo inicia a partir do 14º caracter.
        */
        //unlink( $dir_base . substr( $v, 13 ) );
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: o código acima não excluirá também o próprio arquivo que o execute? Se acontecer de estar no mesmo diretório dos arquivos a serem removidos.

Comment: Aí tem que ser muito burro em colocar o script na mesma pasta onde os arquivos serão exlcuídos né... @Wesley

Comment: kkkk, vai saber... pelo menos funcionou aqui :) , obrigado.